# Using a VCL dll in a firemonkey application

Tags: dll, firemonkey, vcl, getprocaddress, c++builder-xe5

Is it possible to use VCL dll in a firemonkey application?
I am trying to dynamically link a VCL dll to my firemonkey app.
The GetProcAddress returns NULL;
Could this be due to incompatability btw the two frameworks?

Is there any particular code i need to add to my FM app to get the VCL working?

Thanks & Regards,
Priya

Comment: Please show your actual code. Either your `GetProcAddress()` call is specifying the wrong decorated function name, or your DLL has dependencies that are not present with the DLL.